# How to convert float or double to string represented in non-standard base

Tags: c++, string, numbers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std; 
main()
{
  float input = FLT_MAX;

  std::ostringstream buff;
  buff.precision(39);
  buff << input;
  cout << buff.str();   

}
```

How do I convert float or double to a number in base other than decimal? 
I'd like to express the number in these bases: 2; 4; 8; 16; 32; 64.

But even using unsigned long long int is not enough as it can't store numbers of such a high exponent.

Any ideas?

Edit: 
I'd like to convert DBL_MAX as well, as I'm working on a program which is supposed to find and display limits of the basic data types.

This code fails at the second iteration:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std; 
main()
{
  float input = FLT_MAX;
  cout.precision(39); 

  while (floor(input) != 0)
  {
    cout << input << endl;
    input /= 10;
  }

}
```

Can anyone think of other way than using arbitrary precision arithmetics?

Comment: Standard streams don't do this for floating point numbers IIRC.  You'll have to convert them to strings by yourself.

Comment: Printed in what form? Sign, fraction and exponent?

Comment: decimal and possibly with exponent e.g. 0.333333333333̅₍₁₀₎ = 0.1₍₃₎, or 1e-1₍₃₎ (can't think of an example in binary or in other system listed)

Comment: Doing this well is really hard. People get PhDs studying this kind of thing. Doing a half-assed job is fairly easy, and if that's good enough, the answers you'll get here will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test the program but I think this should be fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

char GetChar(int num)
{
    if (num <= 9) return '0' + num;
    return 'A' + num - 10;
}

int main()
{
    int base; std::cin >> base;
    double d;
    std::cin >> d;

    auto i = (long long)d;
    d -= i;

    std::string res;

    while (i)
        res += GetChar(i % base), i /= base;

    std::reverse(res.begin(), res.end());
    res += '.';

    // to stop in case of a repeating fraction.
    int MaximumPrecision = 30;

    do
    {
        d *= base;
        i = (long long)d;
        d -= i;
        res += GetChar(i);

    } while (d > 0 && MaximumPrecision--);

    std::cout << res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for d = DBL_MAX, which is important for me as I'm working on a program which is supposed to show limits for each of the basic data types.